# How can I have the VS Debugger break in the correct location for exceptions thrown in Async methods in a Console App?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I'm writing a console app that uses lots of async methods; so I've made an async Main method that I can await in:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync(args).Wait();
}

static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    // Can use await here
}
```

However, when an exception occurs; the debugger will always break me on the `.Wait()` call. This is not a very good experience.

Is there anything I can do so that the debugger breaks where the exception occurs rather than here? I'm using VS2015 and targeting .NET 4.6 if that influences the answer.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084983/debugger-not-breaking-stopping-for-exceptions-in-async-method)

Comment: See [the second part of this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/20/finding-swallowed-and-async-exceptions-using-intellitrace-in-vs2015.aspx).